# Cant use dynamic content of any?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm building a service parsing some json string to object. I did not get the full object so several of the properties withtin the object is null.

When using "Data operations" to parse the JSON from the example data null becomes type "any". Every other property with data is defined as types string, number and so on works.

But properties defined as 'any' is not usable in the following steps in my logic app.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. It's normal that the expression editor can't find the properties, since they don't have a type. You can manually edit the schema of the "Parse JSON"-connector and update the "any"-types to the expected datatype or regenerate the schema with a more accurate sample.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Compose accept "any" so token of type "any" should show up, we will investigate and fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in our schema generator.

For input like

```
{
"foo": null
}
```

We should generate schema like

```
{
"foo": {}
}
```

Instead of

```
{
"foo": { "type": "any"}
}
```

We will be fixing this soon, in the meantime, remove `"type": "any"` should make the token show in in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **code view** if you are developing in Visual studio. You will get used to expression building in json easier rather than using designer. Sooner designer will be getting better and better.